# Estoy obteniendo error con Supabase y Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, nextjs, supabase

quiero hacer una consulta con el paquete de supabase: @supabase/supabase-js en Nextjs

desde el server Side Rendering, al momento del request time me lanza un error, pero entonces si lo hago en el client si funciona, tengo esta duda de que si el paquete de supabase soporte SSG?

este es el error y el código[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces desde el cliente si se realiza completa: [image: Error que me lanza desde el SSG]

Comment: Hola Edwin, bienvenido, la pregunta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, por favor, edita tu pregunta, elimina las imágenes, y agrega tu código y mensajes de error como texto, así evitarás recibir votos negativos y lograrás que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, gracias. mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor